# Difference between access() with F_OK|R_OK and checking NULL pointer?

Tags: c, file-io, file-permissions, fopen, file-access

I'd like to open a file, but there is three cases which can happen:

1. fopen() doesn't allocate everything (eg. memory limit).
2. The file doesn't exist.
3. I don't have read permissions.

I know about checking `NULL` pointer:

```c
FILE *f = fopen(fname, "r");
if (f == NULL) {
    // 
}
```

But I also know about `access()`:

```c
if (access(fname, F_OK|R_OK) != 0) {
    //
}
```

I tried to remove the permission checking for the file and use only the checking of `NULL` pointer. It works for every case.

What is the difference between using `access()` with `F_OK|R_OK` and checking `NULL` pointer?

*If we won't give an advantage to checking `NULL` pointer, because of checking memory limit.*

Comment: "*I'd like to open a file*" But `access` doesn't open the file, so you can't compare it to `fopen`.

Comment: @Fredrik How do you parse "*What is difference between using access() with F_OK|R_OK and checking NULL pointer?*" in the context of "*open a file*", then.

Comment: @Fredrik On POSIX `errno` gets set if `fopen` returned `NULL`. In other cases, I don't know that it's possible in a portable way when using `fopen`. Checking `access` after `fopen` is not failsafe, since it is always possible that the file (or permissions) changed between the two calls. Anyway, if that's what the question is actually asking then it should be restated more clearly.

Comment: I can check (read permission; file exists) with `access`, but with `f == NULL` as well. The question is, if there's any difference between them.

Comment: You can check permissions with `access`, and you can read a file (starting) with `fopen`. But having read permissions to a file does not guarantee that reading it will succeed. Those are entirely different operations, and you cannot substitute one for the other.

Answer (score 1):

> What is difference between using access() with F_OK|R_OK and checking NULL pointer?

The two are not really comparable.  Even if you perform a successful test with `access()` first, you still need a null check for the `fopen()`, and if that fails, you still don't know for sure why without checking `errno`.  On the other hand, if you first perform an *un*successful test with `access()`, that doesn't tell you with certainty that a subsequent `fopen()` will fail.  Failure of `access()` and failure of `fopen()` tell you different things.

Part of the issue here is that computing systems are dynamic.  For example, just because a file is absent or inaccessible to me now does not mean that it will not be created or made accessible at some point between now and now + *t*, even for very small *t*.  If your intention is to open the file if that is possible, then the best approach is to go straight to attempting to open it.  It's important to check whether that succeeds, but it is usually pretty unimportant to programmatically evaluate the reason for any failure.  `perror()` and `sys_errlist` provide means to generate appropriate user feedback.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to reliably check the access to a file before opening it, you face the famous [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) problem. So, any solution which consists to use some sort of "atomic" operation is preferable. So, calling *(f)open()* and then check the errors if any would be better than calling *access()* followed by a *(f)open()* call.